# Make text selectable

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011, selection

I'm working in CRM 2011 (**edit**: rollup 13), and I've coded a small (dev) helper for the ribbon which displays the ID of the current record in a modal popup (using [picoModal](https://github.com/Nycto/PicoModal) over any heavier libraries so I can embed the script).

Anyway, something (script or otherwise) in CRM is preventing text selection at a global level making my popup all but useless, I've already tried overriding the most obvious stuff that can disable text selection in my popup, including setting all the browser specific `-foo-user-select: text;` css properties, I've reset the unselectable attribute, and even made a naive attempt to reset the onselectstart event to not `return false;` (which *should* be applied as the popup will be dynamically built by picoModal).

```
picoModal(entityName + ":<div id='info-region' unselectable='off' onselectstart='return true;'  style='user-select: text; -ms-user-select: text; -webkit-user-select: text; -khtml-user-select: text; -moz-user-select: text; -o-user-select: text;'><code><pre>" + str + "</pre></code></div><i>(press [CTRL]+[C] to copy the " + entityName + " entities ID to the clipboard)</i>");
```

As a sleight aside from my main problem that I can't select text in my popup, to simplify copying important data I use some code to select relevant text in the `str` payload so it can be easily copied (which I plagiarised from SO, don't have a link anymore but please cite the author if you know):

```
function selectText(entity) {
    var doc = document;
    var text = doc.getElementById(entity);

    if (document.body.createTextRange) { // ms
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) { // moz, opera, webkit
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

The code works in the test page (cross-browser), but not once it's uploaded to CRM 2011 in internet explorer all the text in the modal popup is unelectable, and in Firefox the text is selectable but the selected range is unfocused by the time it's displayed to the user, so I'm assuming there must be some method of limiting text selection I haven't thought of or I'm not overwriting one of the known ways correctly.

Comment: can you please explain better? you are not able to select the text from the crm form or the text of the modal popup?

Comment: @GuidoPreite yes, I assume CRM disables text selection for the entire web page, you can't select form labels for example then it must selectively enable selection for input elements and the like. But I only want to enable selection for a small part of the screen (the div content in the modal popup). The crux of the question (as I see it) is that CRM is beyond my control and is disabling text selection at a global level in an unknown way, I want to override this behavior for the small piece of web content I do control.

Comment: @GuidoPreite I've tried to clarify the question somewhat. Let me know if there's anything you feel is still unclear. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the class "ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" to make text selectable. To enable text selection for the entire page, set "window._UI_TEXT_SELECTABLE = "1";" in javascript.

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2014/05/selectable-text-on-crm-web-resources-with-clientglobalcontext.html

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a `textarea` to hold the `str` variable

Just call `picoModal` in this way:

```js
picoModal(entityName + "<textarea id='guidarea' readonly rows='1'>" + str + "</textarea><i>(press [CTRL]+[C] to copy the " + entityName + " entities ID to the clipboard)</i>");
document.getElementById('guidarea').focus(); // necessary for Google Chrome
document.getElementById('guidarea').select();
```

and because is a `textarea` the `select()` function is enough to select the text in multiple browsers (tested with IE 9, Chrome 27, Firefox 21)

Comment: Great workaround, implemented and it works first time! I did change the `select()` function to `element.setSelectionRange(str.indexOf("{"), str.indexOf("}") - 1);` to select within the textarea though. I'll leave the question open for today just in case someone can tell me how CRM is limiting text selection and how I can reverse it, though I am using your solution. Thanks

Comment: glad it helped. You can also remove the braces before set the str variable, like `str = str.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');`